# How to filter words based on the position using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python. I use python 3.8 version. I am trying to filter only the first whole word and then last word from the string except the numbers globally for any format using regex.

Thanks in advance

```
   s = 'abcd xyz efgh 1691 2191.7 1296 15.4 efgh eghj'
   print(re.search(r'[A-Za-z]+',s))
   s1 = 'abcd xyz:efgh 1691 2191.7 1296 15.4 efgh'
   print(re.search(r'(\w+)',s))
```

**Output:**

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='abcd'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='abcd'>
```

**Expected Output:**

first word

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='abcd xyz efgh'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='abcd xyz:efgh'>
```

Comment: You want `re.finditer(r'^\w+(?:\s+\w+)*|\w+(?:\s+\w+)*$', s)`

Comment: Your expected output doesn't make any sense, a span from `0` to `4` can't match `'abcd xyz efgh'`

Comment: I just need the logic to filter pattern from the string. Do not look at the output as it is just a sample. If none of them can help, then i will try to figure it myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on just what you provided (I don't know if you needed something more specific) this regex should work:

```py
regex = r'^([\D]+).*?([\D]+)$'
```

- ^ : asserts position at the start of a line
- ([\D]+) : Group 1 --> a group of non-numeric characters of at least 1 match
- .*? : matches any character from 0 to unlimited times as few times as possible
- ([\D]+) : Group 2 --> the same as Group 1
- $ : asserts position at the end of a line

```py
>>> import re 
>>> regex = r'^([\D]+).*?([\D]+)$'
>>> strings = [s, s1]
>>> for string in strings:
       print(re.findall(regex, string))
```

**Output:**

```py
[('abcd xyz efgh ', ' efgh eghj')]
[('abcd xyz:efgh ', ' efgh')]
```

Comment: Can't we use `(?<!\d)` to negate the decimal values? Thanks!

Comment: May you be more specific? An example or something.

Comment: Instead of [\D], can we use (?<!\d)?